# Buildozer on WSL not recognize phone

Tags: kivy, windows-subsystem-for-linux, buildozer

hi i have problem with WSL and buildozer.
the same app/files work on my VM but not on WSL(running from bash). i installed buildozer the same way i did in my VM.
the only difference i saw once in log is (this lines did not show when i run in VM):

1. Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for detailsUG]:        > Connecting to Daemon
2. - daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037

- daemon started successfully
  List of devices attached

Application pushed.
Waiting for application to start.

what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Did the app start?

Comment: in VM yes but with WSL the apk not installed because the phone not recognized

Comment: I also have this problem and I'm pretty sure there's currently no solution to this...

Comment: @Weebify this must have solution because people use it and i found one, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3rCRFuuL9E.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried different USB cables? Pretty sure it needs to be a charging/data cable, not just a charging cable.